# Conflict using the "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having a problem with the *this* keyword.

I've a method that will be called by a third-party JavaScript library **(I cannot modify the library's code)** and inside the method *this* is set to a specific context (from the third party library) so I've defined the TypeScript method like this:

```
class CFoo {
   private foo(value?: number) {
     // get the value of this (returned from the third-party library)
     const model = this;

     // call another method inside the class
     this.anotherMethod();
   }

   private anotherMethod()
   {
   }
}
```

but inside the method I need to call another method inside the same class.

When I try to call the other method I get a JavaScript error "anotherMethod" is not a function.

However if I declare the method in this way

```
private foo = (value?: number) => {
}
```

I can get the correct this from the class point of view, I mean, I can access class members using *this.method()* but I cannot access the value provided by the third-party library through *this*.

I need to access the *this* value provided by the third-party library and I need to be able to call another method inside the class.

How can I solve this?

---

**Update:**

When the method is called

this = {
   name: "xxx",
   age: 40
};

Updating the class based on the comment of @vlaz

```
class CFoo {
   me = this;   // @vlaz suggestion

   private foo(value?: number) {
     // get the value of this (returned from the third-party library)
     const model = this as any;

     /*
      * model = {
      *    name: "xxx",
      *    age: 40
      * };
      *
      */

     // call another method inside the class

     me.anotherMethod();   // typescript error
   }

   private anotherMethod()
   {
   }
}
```

When I try to call *anotherMethod()* the TypeScript compiler is showing the following error

Cannot find name 'me'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.me'?

Comment: Set `self = this` inside your class and exclusively call methods through `self.someMethod`. You don't need to call the variable `self` but it's a decent convention. Another convention is to call it `that` but I personally hate it - `that = this` seems a bit illogical.

Comment: Please show us how you are passing your method to the third party library

Comment: Plenty questions on fat arrow and this.

Comment: I've updated the class based on @vlaz comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CFoo {
    private foo: Function;

    constructor() {
        const self = this;
        this.foo = function (value?: number) {
            // get the value of this (returned from the third-party library)
            const model = this;

            // call another method inside the class
            self.anotherMethod();
        }
    }

    private anotherMethod()
    {
    }
 }
```